# read a file in scala and get key value pairs as Map[String, List[String]]

Tags: scala, apache-spark

i am reading a file and getting the records as a Map[String, List[String]] in spark-scala. similar thing i want to achieve in pure scala form without any spark references(not reading an rdd). what should i change to make it work in a pure scala way

```
rdd
      .filter(x => (x != null) && (x.length > 0))
      .zipWithIndex()
      .map {
        case (line, index) =>
          val array = line.split("~").map(_.trim)
          (array(0), array(1), index)
      }
      .groupBy(_._1)
      .mapValues(x => x.toList.sortBy(_._3).map(_._2))
      .collect
      .toMap
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the most part it will remain the same except for the groupBy part in rdd. Scala List also has the map, filter, reduce etc. methods. So they can be used in almost a similar fashion.

```
val lines = Source.fromFile('filename.txt').getLines.toList
```

Once the file is read and stored in List, the methods can be applied to it.

For the groupBy part, one simple approach can be to sort the tuples on the key. That will effectively cluster the tuples with same keys together.

```
val grouped = scala.util.Sorting.stablesort(arr, (e1: String, e2: String, e3: String) 
               => e1._1 < e2._2)
```

There can be better solutions definitely, but this would effectively do the same task.

Comment: Scala sequences have groupBy too.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with the below approach

```
Source.fromInputStream(
getClass.getResourceAsStream(filePath)).getLines.filter(
    lines =>(lines != null) && (lines.length > 0)).map(_.split("~")).toList.groupBy(_(0)).map{ case (key, values) => (key, values.map(_(1))) }
```